# Cant access action in children component

Tags: reactjs

I'm getting an erro `Cannot read property 'handleDeleteAll' of undefined`.
This is my code:

```
const RecipeList = (props) => {

const Items = props.recipes.map((recipe) => {
  return <RecipeListItem key={recipe.id} recipe={recipe} />
});
      console.log(props);
      return (
        <div>
          <button onClick={this.props.handleDeleteAll}>Remove All</button>
          <div>
            {Items}
          </div>
        </div>
      )
}
export default RecipeList;
```

And this is the repo: https://github.com/kstulgys/fcc-recipe-box/blob/master/src/components/RecipeList.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`RecipeList` is a function not a class. You can access the handler as `props.handleDeleteAll` and not `this.props.handleDeleteAll`.

Comment: Too easy. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

RecipeList is a stateless functional component so this.props is undefined.

Change this line

```
<button onClick={this.props.handleDeleteAll}>Remove All</button>
```

To this line

```
<button onClick={props.handleDeleteAll}>Remove All</button>
```